# Heroku logs shows undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) after trying to setup active storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rails-activestorage

I am trying to push a rails app to heroku and am encountering the following error related to active storage:

Error :

`` undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) ``

Everything is working as expected in development on my local machine. I have ran `bundle exec rails active_storage:install` and the active storage related tables migrate successfully on heroku. However, the error throws when I attempt to seed my database using active storage. It also throws in the heroku console when I attempt to start up to app.

application.rb:

```rb
require 'rails/all'
```

Gemfile:

```rb
gem 'aws-sdk-s3'
```

config/enviornments/production.rb:

```rb
config.active_storage.service = :amazon_dev
```

credentials.yml:

```
aws:
  access_key_id: XXXXX
  secret_access_key: XXXXX
  region: XXXXX
  bucket: XXXXX

# Used as the base secret for all MessageVerifiers in Rails, including the one protecting cookies.
secret_key_base: XXXXX
```

config/storage.yml:

```
amazon_dev:
  service: S3
  access_key_id: <%= Rails.application.credentials.aws[:access_key_id] %>
  secret_access_key: <%= Rails.application.credentials.aws[:secret_access_key] %>
  region: <%= Rails.application.credentials.aws[:region] %>
  bucket: <%= Rails.application.credentials.aws[:bucket] %>
```

Stack trace from heroku consoloe:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    83: from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
    82: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
    81: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
    80: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
    79: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    78: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    77: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    76: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    75: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
    74: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    73: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
    72: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
    71: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
    70: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    69: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    68: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:95:in `perform'
    67: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:15:in `require_application_and_environment!'
    66: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:28:in `require_environment!'
    65: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:337:in `require_environment!'
    64: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
    63: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
    62: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
    61: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    60: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    59: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    58: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    57: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
    56: from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    55: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
    54: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
    53: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    52: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    51: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    50: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    49: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    48: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    47: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    46: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    45: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    44: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
    43: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
    42: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
    41: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    40: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `each'
    39: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:356:in `eager_load!'
    38: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:in `eager_load!'
    37: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:in `each'
    36: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:477:in `block in eager_load!'
    35: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:477:in `each'
    34: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:478:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
    33: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:246:in `require_dependency'
    32: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:85:in `depend_on'
    31: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:334:in `depend_on'
    30: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:47:in `require_or_load'
    29: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:16:in `allow_bootsnap_retry'
    28: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:48:in `block in require_or_load'
    27: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:356:in `require_or_load'
    26: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `load_interlock'
    25: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:13:in `loading'
    24: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:151:in `exclusive'
    23: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:14:in `block in loading'
    22: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `block in load_interlock'
    21: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:378:in `block in require_or_load'
    20: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
    19: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
    18: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
    17: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    16: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    15: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    14: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    13: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
    12: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activestorage-5.2.3/app/models/active_storage/blob.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
    11: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activestorage-5.2.3/app/models/active_storage/blob.rb:235:in `<class:Blob>'
    10: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `run_load_hooks'
     9: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `each'
     8: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:52:in `block in run_load_hooks'
     7: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:67:in `execute_hook'
     6: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:62:in `with_execution_control'
     5: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `block in execute_hook'
     4: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `instance_eval'
     3: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activestorage-5.2.3/lib/active_storage/engine.rb:95:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
     2: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/erb.rb:876:in `result'
     1: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/erb.rb:876:in `eval'
(erb):6:in `<main>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

**EDIT**

after doing some digging, here is the source code of the file in the activestorage gem which this error seems to be coming from:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.2.3/activestorage/lib/active_storage/engine.rb

So it appears as though the issue almost certainly has to do with the storage.yml file, but I cannot seem to pinpoint what it is.

**Solution**

After tinkering with storage.yml a bit, the error went away and everything worked as expected. I suspect that there were extra spaces in my storage.yml file that I didn't notice.

Comment: but you know where on your code is tring to use [] and can be a nilClass?

Comment: I my guess that code in the active storage gem is using []. The following links give me a hint that it has something to do with storage.yml, but I still can't find the problem. https://rubyinrails.com/2017/07/21/rails-introduces-active-storage-for-file-uploads/ https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rubyonrails-talk/RaFBG6wi2K0

Comment: The reason I had this issue is because I kept commented out lines in storage.yml and rails seemed to still attempt to read the commented out (unused) keys. The solution for me was to delete the commented out lines.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you solved the issue. I had the same error, however my problem was I didn't have the RAILS_MASTER_KEY set in heroku.

You can add it with the CLI with `heroku config:set RAILS_MASTER_KEY=<your-master-key-here>` or use the GUI in the settings page of your heroku app. The master key comes from your config/master.key file, and isn't and shouldn't be tracked by git.

This may be an obvious step not to forget to some, but I thought I'd post this in case anyone else runs into this like me.